# Redirect while keeping URL in browser by DNS settings only - is it possible?

Tags: dns, redirect, http-redirect

I had an argument with my friend about domain redirects. He is convinced that you can redirect one domain to another by using DNS records only, **showing source URL in browser instead of target URL**. I mean, without any access to webserver. I don't think this is the case but can't find a direct proof that it's impossible.

So I'm curious. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. It's sometimes called [Stealth Forwarding](https://www.dynadot.com/community/help/question/whats-stealth-forward) and may or may not be offered by your domain name registrar.